# How get index of array with jq

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I want search this string `tb1qpvtnfqqs3cp4ly4375km7n5sga8hkdkujkm854` in that structure

```
{
  "txid": "67bc5194442dc350312a7c0a5fc7ef912c31bf00b23349b4c3afdf177c91fb2f",
  "hash": "8392ded0647e4166eda342cee409c7d0e1e3ffab24de41866d2e6a7bd0a245b3",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 245,
  "vsize": 164,
  "weight": 653,
  "locktime": 1764124,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "69eed058cbd18b3bf133c8341582adcd76a4d837590d3ae8fa0ffee1d597a8c3",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "0014759fc698313da549948940508df6db93a319096e",
        "hex": "160014759fc698313da549948940508df6db93a319096e"
      },
      "txinwitness": [
        "3044022014a8eb758063c52bc970d42013e653f5d3fb3c190b55f7cfa72680280cc5138602202a873b5cad4299b2f52d8cccb4dcfa66fa6ec256d533788f54440d4cdad7dd6501",
        "02ec8ba22da03ed1870fe4b9f9071067a6a1fda6f582c5c858644e44bd401bfc0a"
      ],
      "sequence": 4294967294
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.37841708,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 686bc8ce41505642c96f3eb99919fff63f4c0f11",
        "hex": "0014686bc8ce41505642c96f3eb99919fff63f4c0f11",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "tb1qdp4u3njp2pty9jt086uejx0l7cl5crc3x3phwd"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 0.00022000,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 0b173480108e035f92b1f52dbf4e90474f7b36dc",
        "hex": "00140b173480108e035f92b1f52dbf4e90474f7b36dc",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "tb1qpvtnfqqs3cp4ly4375km7n5sga8hkdkujkm854"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "hex": "02000000000101c3a897d5e1fe0ffae83a0d5937d8a476cdad821534c833f13b8bd1cb58d0ee690000000017160014759fc698313da549948940508df6db93a319096efeffffff022c6b410200000000160014686bc8ce41505642c96f3eb99919fff63f4c0f11f0550000000000001600140b173480108e035f92b1f52dbf4e90474f7b36dc02473044022014a8eb758063c52bc970d42013e653f5d3fb3c190b55f7cfa72680280cc5138602202a873b5cad4299b2f52d8cccb4dcfa66fa6ec256d533788f54440d4cdad7dd65012102ec8ba22da03ed1870fe4b9f9071067a6a1fda6f582c5c858644e44bd401bfc0a1ceb1a00",
  "blockhash": "000000009acb8b4f06a97beb23b3d9aeb3df71052dabec94465933b564c27f50",
  "confirmations": 2,
  "time": 1591687001,
  "blocktime": 1591687001
}
```

I'd like to get the index of vout, in this case 1. is it possible with jq?

Comment: When you say `index`, do you mean the index in .vout or the corresponding value of "n"?  What if there is no "n" key?  What if the string is not found? What if there are multiple occurrences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you want.

I guess you want the `n` of the element of `vout` that contains the given address in its addresses list. That can be achieved with

```
jq '.vout[]
    | select(.scriptPubKey.addresses[] == "tb1qpvtnfqqs3cp4ly4375km7n5sga8hkdkujkm854")
    | .n
   ' file.json
```

You can also use

```
select((.scriptPubKey.addresses[]
    | contains("tb1qpvtnfqqs3cp4ly4375km7n5sga8hkdkujkm854")))
```

to search for the address.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that you want the index in .vout of the first object which has the given string as a leaf value, and that you have in mind using 0 as the index origin.

A simple and reasonably efficient jq program that finds all such indices is as follows:

```
.vout
| range(0;length) as $i
| if any(.[$i]|..;
         . == "tb1qpvtnfqqs3cp4ly4375km7n5sga8hkdkujkm854") 
  then $i 
  else empty
  end
```

With the given input, this in fact yields 1, which is in accordance with the problem description, so we seem to be on right track.

To get the first index, you could wrap the above in `first(...)`, but in that case the result would be the empty stream if there is no occurrence.  So perhaps you would prefer to wrap the above in `first(...) // null`

Comment: Is this `range ... as` syntax documented?

Comment: The `...` is an ellipsis. Replace the ... with the code of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```bash
$vout={{ your json }}

$value="tb1qpvtnfqqs3cp4ly4375km7n5sga8hkdkujkm854"

result=$(echo "$vout" | jq -r '.[0] | select($value)')
```